# MySql Get Records from Specific month to month

Tags: php, mysql, csv

```
<?php
$server = 'xxxxxxxx';
$login = 'xxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxx';
$db = 'customers';
$table = 'account_id';
$filename = 'records.csv';
mysql_connect($server, $login, $password);
mysql_select_db($db);
$fp = fopen($filename, "w+");

$res = mysql_query("SELECT  `Emp_No` , `First_Name` , `Last_Nmae` ,  DATE_FORMAT( `Date`, '%b %d %Y' ), `Dept` , `Location` ,`Comment1`, `Comment2`
                   FROM $table
                   WHERE `Account` LIKE 'BJC100' 
                   AND  month(Date) >= 7 AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -365 DAY) 
                   AND month(Date) <= 6 AND DATE_FORMAT( Date, '%Y' ) = DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y' ) AND length(Emp_No) > 0 ");

//July (7)anniversary

mysql_data_seek($res, 0);


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    $line = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach($row as $value) {

     $line .= $comma . '' . str_replace('', '', $value) . '';

        $comma = ",";
    }
    $line .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $line);

}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

So I'm trying to get records from July 1 of prevous year to current year June 30
If I remove the "AND month(Date) <= 6 AND DATE_FORMAT( Date, '%Y' ) = DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y' ) " It will save to a CSV file. As soon as I put it back in it gives me a blank CSV file.

Can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To expand on @Dagon feedback, using MONTH() generally makes time comparisons more difficult, especially when you need to go back to a previous year.  Make a start datetime value (e.g., CAST('07/01/2012' as DATETIME) and an end datetime value AND use the "BETWEEN" operator.

Comment: @AgRizzo Thanks for that information, I didn't want to use Between due to the fact this script runs daily to update a different system. If I put in a starting date I would have to remember to change the date in the script each year. Can't say I'll be around in a year!